# One Hot Encoded Labels back to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, one-hot-encoding

I want to apply some classifiers to a dataframe and thus had to one-hot-encode the df. I now have the labels, but don't know how to proceed? How do I get the labels back to a df type, and how do I work with the new df?

I have a reduced dataframe with no NaN values. I first label-enocoded it and then proceeded to one-hot-encode it.

```
categorical_feature_mask = reduced_df.dtypes==object
categorical_cols = reduced_df.columns[categorical_feature_mask].tolist()
categorical_cols

reduced_df[categorical_cols] = reduced_df[categorical_cols].apply(lambda col: le.fit_transform(col))

labeled_df = reduced_df[categorical_cols]
enc = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder()

enc.fit(labeled_df)
onehotlabels = enc.transform(labeled_df).toarray()
onehotlabels
```

I get a numpy-array with shape (14737, 990), full of zeros and ones (which is of course what I wanted), but how do I 'merge' it back to my dataframe (i.e. with the labels etc.)

My goal is not to 'decode' the labels but to 'merge' the encoded columns with other columns from my original df.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to go back from ONE-HOT-ENCODED labels to single column using sklearn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56266011/how-to-go-back-from-one-hot-encoded-labels-to-single-column-using-sklearn)

Comment: also possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56584288/one-hot-encoding-in-scikit-learn-for-only-part-of-the-dataframe#comment99746857_56584288

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as follows:

```
reduced_df=pd.DataFrame({
'some_column': [35, 21, 39, 44, 62, 54, 85, 92, 25, 81],
'color'      : ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black'],
'brand'      : ['Chrysler', 'BMW', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes'],
})

categorical_feature_mask = reduced_df.dtypes==object
categorical_cols = reduced_df.columns[categorical_feature_mask].tolist()
labeled_df = reduced_df[categorical_cols]
enc = OneHotEncoder()
enc.fit(labeled_df)

onehotlabels = enc.transform(labeled_df).toarray()

new_columns=list()
for col, values in zip(labeled_df.columns, enc.categories_):
    new_columns.extend([col + '_' + str(value) for value in values])

new_df= pd.concat([reduced_df, pd.DataFrame(onehotlabels, columns=new_columns)], axis='columns')
new_df
```

The output is:

```
Out[44]: 
   some_column  color     brand  color_black       ...        color_red  brand_BMW  brand_Chrysler  brand_Mercedes
0           35    red  Chrysler          0.0       ...              1.0        0.0             1.0             0.0
1           21  green       BMW          0.0       ...              0.0        1.0             0.0             0.0
2           39   blue  Mercedes          0.0       ...              0.0        0.0             0.0             1.0
3           44  black  Mercedes          1.0       ...              0.0        0.0             0.0             1.0
4           62  black  Mercedes          1.0       ...              0.0        0.0             0.0             1.0
5           54  black  Mercedes          1.0       ...              0.0        0.0             0.0             1.0
6           85  black  Mercedes          1.0       ...              0.0        0.0             0.0             1.0
7           92  black  Mercedes          1.0       ...              0.0        0.0             0.0             1.0
8           25  black  Mercedes          1.0       ...              0.0        0.0             0.0             1.0
9           81  black  Mercedes          1.0       ...              0.0        0.0             0.0             1.0

[10 rows x 10 columns]
```