# How to Avoid getting NaN when applying One Hot Encoding in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, jupyter-lab

I am training a machine learning model to predict housing prices for my home country. I was unsure on how to apply one hot encoding to my data: so I copied the code from here: [One Hot Encoded Labels back to DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56948297/one-hot-encoded-labels-back-to-dataframe).

It appears to work well, except that my other labels are now getting replaced by NaN.
[Before applying the One Hot Encoding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHaWx.png), and after I apply one hot encoding, [this is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvFy0.png)

The code I have used is as follows:

```
print(ds.head())

categorical_feature_mask = ds.dtypes==object
categorical_cols = ds.columns[categorical_feature_mask].tolist()
labeled_ds = ds[categorical_cols]
enc = OneHotEncoder()
enc.fit(labeled_ds)

onehotlabels = enc.transform(labeled_ds).toarray()

new_columns=list()
for col, values in zip(labeled_ds.columns, enc.categories_):
    new_columns.extend([col + '_' + str(value) for value in values])

ds= pd.concat([ds, pd.DataFrame(onehotlabels, columns=new_columns)], axis='columns')

names = ['location', 'property_type']
ds.drop(names, axis=1, inplace=True)

ds.head()
```

Any ideas on what may be causing this issue?

Comment: I guess the problem is with the contact part. Make sure when you are concatenating both of the dataframe has got the same index. So use `.reset_index`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this issue due to index being different.

Your `ds` may have different index (not starting from 0 and continuous) but your one hot label dataframe is starting from 0 and continuous.

So when you are going for concatenation. Since indices are not same you are getting nan there.

Please check the shape also to confirm whether the issue due to indices mismatch or not.

**To solve:**

```
pd.concat([ds.reset_index(drop=True), pd.DataFrame(onehotlabels, columns=new_columns)], axis='columns')
```

or

(if you wanna maintain the same index as `ds` one)

```
pd.concat([ds, pd.DataFrame(onehotlabels, columns=new_columns), index=ds.index], axis='columns')
```

Comment: yes 
`ds = pd.concat([ds, pd.DataFrame(onehotlabels, columns=new_columns, index=ds.index)], axis='columns')` worked perfectly! Thank you :)